# HTML / JAVA Scraping

Tags: java, html, r, html-parsing

What is the best way to scrape the betting forecast from this page in R?

http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/cards/card.sd?race_id=632478&r_date=2015-08-24#raceTabs=sc_

I have tried this:

```
CardURL = getURL(paste("http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/cards/card.sd?race_id=",race_id,"&r_date=",r_date,"#raceTabs=sc_")) 

doc = (htmlParse(CardURL, asText=TRUE))

plain.text = data.frame(xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue))
```

But it doesn't show the betting forecast as you need to be logged in (prior to 9am). Is there some way to scrape the page using member credentials/automatically login? And is `htmlParse` the best way to scrape this webpage?

Comment: You can login to the page from R as well, but probably it will be easier for you to login from your browser, save the cookie and pass it to `RCurl`. IMO `htmlParse` is a decent tool for your needs, although many R users rather suggest `curl` or the `httr` packages instead of `RCurl` and `rvest` instead of `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

curl and httr are great packages for providing http client functionality. This rbloggers article gives a good intro, and a link to the curl vignette: http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-curl-package-a-modern-r-interface-to-libcurl/

I think this may be a better solution for you, as the package will be able to handle authentication and parsing together.